# Conditional CMD in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

I'd like to run `CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]` if a dev script is present in package.json, otherwise `CMD ["npm", "start"]`

Is there an idiomatic docker way for doing this? I suppose my CMD could be a bash script which checks for the presence of 'npm run dev'. Is there a cleaner way to do it than that?

Comment: You can write a bash script and run that. Running unnecessary commands in Docker would create more layer - which is bad. Something like this can be used.
`if [ -e "$file_name" ]; then
  echo "File exists"
fi
`

Comment: Reference for `Minimize Docker Layers`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#each-container-should-have-only-one-concern

Answer (score 9):

You could dynamically create a `bash` script containing appropriate command:

```
RUN bash -c "if npm run | grep -q dev ; then echo npm run dev > run.sh; else echo npm start > run.sh; fi; chmod 777 run.sh;"
CMD ./run.sh
```

- `if npm run | grep -q dev` will check if `dev` script is present in `package.json`. Running `npm run` with no arguments will list all runable scripts and `grep -q dev` will return `true` only if `dev` is among them.
- `echo command > run.sh` will create a file with provided command
- `chmod 777 run.sh` will make the `run.sh` executable
- `CMD ./run.sh` will execute created file

Answer (score 1):

The Dockerfile syntax does not cover that such use case. You have to rely on scripts to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

If CMD is the only place you want to be different based on the node environment, then it is pretty straightforward. This is what I use sometimes:

```
CMD yarn "$(if [ $NODE_ENV = 'production' ] ; then echo 'start' ; else echo 'dev'; fi)"
```

> Note that this is yarn, but you can change that to npm

Then the mentioned scripts (`yarn start` and `yarn dev`) will be triggered based on the value of NODE_ENV.

NODE_ENV is set to 'production' by default in most cloud providers BTW.

Comment: this doesn't work at all

Comment: It worked for me. Let me test it once again

Answer (score -1):

Reading your package.json within your Dockerfile won't make any sense. What you can do is having separate Dockerfiles for dev environment and another Dockerfile which doesn't contain "dev" command. This way would provide you more control over the Docker images that you are building as well.